# com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Document has no pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

Im facing some problems with PDF Documents:

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Document has no pages.
INFO   | jvm 2    | main    | 2019/07/12 15:14:17.389 |         at 
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPagesTree.generateTree(PdfPagesTree.java:263)   
[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 2    | main    | 2019/07/12 15:14:17.389 |         at 
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:837) ~ 
[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 2    | main    | 2019/07/12 15:14:17.389 |         at 
com.app.document.PdfHelper.close(PdfHelper.java:128) ~
```

I can't post my code right now , but any hint about why is this is happening ? I must know the possible reasons .

Comment: Hard to say, without your code...

Comment: It looks like your code had errors.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF needs to have at least one page.  If you are creating new PDFs and you have an error in your code so it fails to create a page in the new document. Then you could certainly run into this.

Another possibility is the page creation failed due to a bug in the PDF library are using.